# Min property in angular datepicker

Tags: angular

**I am trying to disable the date using min property in my angular application. How ever it does not work for me. Not understanding whether I am implementing it the wrong way or so. Any suggestions?**

**.HTML file**

```
<input matInput [min]="minDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" [formControl]="serializedDate" [readonly]="true"
                            (dateChange)="deliveryDateChangeOrNot($event.value)" />
```

**.Ts**

**file I just want to use the date from rfq.eta (and the format from json is MM/DD/YYYY - HH:MM that is why i am using split method)**

```
minDate : any = "";

deliveryDateChangeOrNot(dateValue: any) {
    if (dateValue != '') {
      this.hasUnsavedDataDate = true;
      this.inputsaveDraftRfqData();
    }
    if(this.rfq.eta){
      let splitValue = this.rfq.eta.split('-');
      this.minDate.setValue(new Date(splitValue[0]));
    }
  }
```

Comment: 1st question to ask yourself, what is the type of minDate? It has initial value of the empty string but later you are trying `this.minDate.setValue` like it is a form control

Comment: thankyou for pointing that out. I just removed the setvalue function and it is working fine but the only thing is that now when i open the popup and then select one date then the dates are getting disabled and not at the very first time when i open the popup @AndrewAllen

Answer (score -1):

use [minDate] for the minimum selectable date, [min] use to check minimum valid date

Comment: Do you mean using minDate instead of min? @Muhammad Ahsan

Comment: Tried that but does not work

Comment: I have mentioned the use case for both you can use them based on your scenarios for more details check the API spec of the Date picker
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api

if you are not successful please make stackblitz example of your app so we can debug it for you precisely